# How to use a public keypair .pem file for ansible playbooks?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to use a public aws keypair .pem file for running ansible playbooks.  I want to do this without changing my `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and I can't create a new keypair from my current `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and apply it to the ec2 instances I am trying to change.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 1.9.6
  configured module search path = None
```

Here is my hosts file (note that my actual ip is replaced with `1.2.3.4`).  This is probably the issue since I need a way to set a public key variable and use that:

```
[all_servers:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file = ./mykeypair.pem

[dashboard]
1.2.3.4 dashboard_domain=my.domain.info
```

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: dashboard
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: ubuntu

  tasks:
    - name: ping
      ping:
```

This is the command I am using to run it:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts test.yml
```

It results in the following error:

```
fatal: [1.2.3.4] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey).
    while connecting to 1.2.3.4:22
```

There is no problem with my keypair:

```
$ ssh -i mykeypair.pem ubuntu@1.2.3.4 'whoami'
ubuntu
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please revert edits to the question – bring back original hosts file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok little mistakes I guess you can't have spaces in host file variables and need to define the group you are applying the vars to.  This hosts file works with it all:

```
[dashboard:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=./mykeypair.pem

[dashboard]
1.2.3.4 dashboard_domain=my.domain.info
```

Answer (score 16):

I have come across this and all what I had to do was to run the below

```
#ssh-agent bash
#ssh-add ~/.ssh/keypair.pem
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It keeps authorization information out of the hosts file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I would add that the .pem file should have the correct permission (ie: chmod 400 keypair.pem)

Comment: works well with zsh. thanks, ps: just use the 2nd command

Answer (score 0):

Open your pem file with notepad copy keys,
then go to machine (AWS instance) create file in user home dir (vi file name)
then paste your pem keys (which copied above),
now type command:

```
# ssh-agent bash 
# ssh-add ~/.ssh/your filename
```

The important thing this configuration will be your local machine or that machine (instance) which want to access other instances
`ssh ubuntu@machine` IP which you want to access